# Why isn't my program reading the file correctly?

Tags: java, filereader

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String filename = args[0]; //reads command line argument 1 as filename
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename)); //reads filename into program,and opens it for analysis
        File.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); //creates an array list to store chars to transfer for reading from the file
        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            list.add(inFile.next()); //adds each char letter to the list
        }
        File.close();//closes file stream
        char[][] array1 = new char[10][20];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            array1[i] = list.get(i).toCharArray(); //converts array list -> char array
        }
int[] CountA = new int[200]; 
        CountA = CharSearch(array1, 'A');
        int[] CountB = new int[200]; 
        CountB = CharSearch(array1, 'B');
        int[] CountC = new int[200]; 
        CountC = CharSearch(array1, 'C');
        int totalA = 0;
        int totalB = 0;
        int totalC = 0;
        int totalgroupsA = 0;
        int totalgroupsB = 0;
        int totalgroupsC = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i > CountA.length; i++) {
            if (CountA[i] != 0) {
                totalA += CountA[i];
                totalgroupsA++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i > CountB.length; i++) {
            if (CountB[i] != 0) {
                totalB += CountB[i];
                totalgroupsB++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i > CountC.length; i++) {
            if (CountC[i] != 0) {
                totalC += CountC[i];
                totalgroupsC++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(filename);
        for (int i = 0; i> array1.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j> array1.length; j++){
                System.out.println(array1[i][j]);
                if (array1[i][j] == array1[i][20])
                    System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The number of groups of A is: " + totalgroupsA);
        System.out.println("The number of groups of B is: " + totalgroupsB);
        System.out.println("The number of groups of C is: " + totalgroupsC);
        while (totalA != totalB && totalA != totalC && totalB != totalC){
        if (totalA > totalB && totalA > totalC) {
            System.out.println("The largest group is " + totalA);
        } else if (totalB > totalA && totalB > totalC) {
            System.out.println("The largest group is " + totalB);
        } else if (totalC > totalB && totalC > totalA) {
            System.out.println("The largest group is " + totalC);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File is not found: " + e.getMessage());//catches and sends out an error message
    }

}
static int[] CharSearch(char[][] array1, char a) {
    int w = 10;
    int h = 20;
    int[] rst = new int[w * h];
    int count = 0;
    int next_region = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
            if (array1[i][j] == a) {
                continue;
            }
            count += 1;
            int k = 0;
            boolean connected = false;
            //if connected to the left          
            if (j > 0 && array1[i][j - 1] == array1[i][j]) {
                count += 1;
                connected = true;
            }
            //if connected upwards
            if (i > 0 && array1[i - 1][j] == array1[i][j] && (connected = false)) {
                count += 1;
                connected = true;
            }
            if (!connected) {
                k = next_region;
                rst[k] = count;
                next_region++;
            }
        }

    }
    return rst;
}}
```

Something is up with this portion of my program, it isn't reading in the file I have correctly, as the output seems to go to nothing. I actually also added something else to see if the file is being read, but there is still no output. Fixed a bit more of the code so that there are no problems~. The file is being read in, and its being converted into the char array, now the only issue is that there is nothing being outputted still...

Edit: now here is the output so you can see the whole code i did- charsearch is an algorithm I wrote

Comment: What do you expect as an output? A list of lines?

Comment: Well you're not writing any output... what did you expect to see? Also, using a variable name which is the same as a type name (`File`) is a *really* bad idea.

Comment: well, there is a lot more to the program, i can put that up as well, the output part at least

Comment: This is an example of how not to do it.  Throw this code away immediately and Google for "java read a file example".  There are millions of examples of how to do it, all better than this one.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1[i]))` in your last loop

Comment: When I do that, the file is being seen getting read in actually. There still is no output however..

Comment: If you want to read all lines from a text file, don't be bothered and use `Files.readAllLines()`!

Comment: You do realize if two groups are equal your if-else structure can fail? For example, what if group A is 5 , B is 5, and C is 3? None of those conditions will be true.

Comment: Oh, man that is true.

Answer (score 0):

In this line, you are declaring a "File" variable that hides java.io.File:

```
Scanner File = new Scanner(new File(filename)); //reads filename into program,and opens it for analysis
```

All the subsequent uses of "File" will refer to your local variable, not to java.io.File.

You should use different name for you local variable. Also, the standard naming convention for Java is to name variables starting with a lower case character, so you should do that so that you do not confuse and annoy other Java programmers.

Comment: thanks, i just fixed that part, but there is still no output from the file in the program.

Comment: Are you saying that there is absolutely no output, or that you are not seeing all the output you expect? Is the program exiting normally, or is the console displaying an uncaught exception?

Comment: There are no uncaught exceptions,

Comment: file1.txt
(the table is located here- its being read in)

The number of groups of A is: 0
The number of groups of B is: 0
The number of groups of C is: 0 
is the output i am getting

Comment: Please provide the CharSearch() implementation. I suspect that that method is not returning an array with any non-zero values. Also, there is no reason for you to preallocate the result arrays, like so: "int[] CountA = new int[200];", since the array value will be overwritten by whatever CharSearch() returns. There are many other improvement that can be made. By the way, please up-vote this answer if you feel it has helped you.

Comment: I just edited my OP with the CharSearch() algorithm. Yeah, there is probably a million things wrong with this programming. A lot of it is self learning, as the book i received for my class as well as the lecture itself isn't the most helpful when it comes to actually writing the code... so I have to learn most of it for myself. and I changed the allocation in my original program.

Comment: First obvious problem in CharSearch() is that the inner loop is only allowing j to go up to 9, not 19.  You can use "for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {...
"

Comment: ok I can see that, since array1.length= 10 and not 20... got that and edited it.